# Nav bar links and a h1

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a nav bar with a header and then 2 links on each side.
But when it test it on a local host it seems to make it like this when i want to it be all horizontal.

```
LINK LINK
TITLE(h1)
LINK LINK
```

Html:

```
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
    <a href="index.html">Index</a>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="index.html">James</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#navigation 
{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
height: 120px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
background-color:#666;}

#navigation a 
{
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation h1
{
font-size: 25px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Why does it go like this?

```
LINK LINK
TITLE
LINK LINK?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide clarification? Unless I'm reading it wrong.. It sounds like it's doing what you want...

Comment: Sorry about that forgot to put what it looks like into a code box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided, it seems that your Title "h1" is set to `display:block` . Change it to `display: inline` .

Comment: Glad I could help! If you could, kindly mark this as the correct answer please... =)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `<h1>Home</h1>` after `<div id="navigation">`. Your code should be

```
<body>
<div id="navigation">
<h1>Home</h1>
    <a href="index.html">Index</a>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="index.html">James</a>
</div>
</body>
```